# check username by regexp

Tags: php, regex

for my registration i check username with my regex -- Username must contain more than 3 and less than 20 characters. Also username can contain only lphanumeric characters and " _ ", " . ", " - ".

```
/^([\w\.\-]{3,20})$/isu.
```

Now i want to check (p-) too, if this exist return false username cant content (p-)

```
private $regExpUsername = "/^([\w\.\-]{3,20})$/isu";

    private function checkUsername($username){
        if(!preg_match($this->regExpUsername, $username)){
            $this->addError(ERR_ENTER_USERNAME);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `s` modifier makes no sense there. And "if this exist return false username cant content (p-)" explanation is not clear enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understood that you don't want the username to end with a `-`. This would be this

```
^[\w.-]{2,19}[\w.]$
```

Since `\w` contains the underscore this would allow the username to end with an underscore, but not with a dash, since the dash is not part of the character class, that defines the last character.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31djv)

As zerkms commented the `s` modifier makes no sense here, because it changes the behaviour of the `.` special character that you don't use.

Also the `i` modifier makes no sense, it would match lower and uppercase letters, but you don't use letters to define your expression.

**Update**

Then you need a [negative lookahead](http://regexr.com?31dkk)

```
^(?!.*p-)[\w.-]{3,20}$
```

`(?!.*p-)` is a negative lookahead, this assertion will fail as soon as there is a `p-` anywhere in the string.

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?31dkk)

Comment: No, i want that the username ton contain "p-" for example davp-id